# Having Issue on Targeting Element Parent's Closest div

Tags: jquery, html

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behsei) and let me know why I am not able to `slideUp()` the `.err`

```js
$(function () {

    $("input").on("click", function () {
        $(this).parent().closest("err").slideUp();

    });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");
body {
    padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" id="login-form" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group input-group" id="emailBox"> <span class="input-group-addon">
            @
          </span>

            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" type="email" id="email">
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger err" role="alert">Field Can Not Be Empty</div>
        <div class="form-group input-group" id="passBox"> <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock">
            </i>
          </span>

            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" id="password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Access</button>
            </button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

ni/jq5g3yt9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `.err` element is the `sibling` of the parent of `input`, use `next()` instead of `closest()`. Also, you missed `.` *class-selector* of `err`.

```
$(this).parent().next(".err").slideUp();
```

Demo:

```js
$(function() {

  $("input").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().next(".err").slideUp();

  });
});
```

```css
.err {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" id="login-form" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group input-group" id="emailBox"> <span class="input-group-addon">
            @
          </span>

      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" type="email" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger err" role="alert">Field Can Not Be Empty</div>
    <div class="form-group input-group" id="passBox"> <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock">
            </i>
          </span>

      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" id="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" id="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Access</button>
      </button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```